# Changing the perspective using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on a project, in which I use a  chessboard, the problem that I'm facing, is when I recognize the board I want to crop the part of the frame that contains it and put it "straight", for that I'm using the `cv::warpPerspective` function,  bellow is my code and the result that I get :

```
int main (){
    cv::Size board(6,4);
    cv::Mat src,result,quad,transformationMatrix;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> imageCorners;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> top, bot;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> not_a_rect_shape;
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    char fileName[20] = "MYROI";
    int index =0;
    int key = 0 ;   
    cap >> src;
    while ( key != 27){
        cap >> src;
        if(cv::findChessboardCorners(src,board,imageCorners,CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS)){
            int xMin =imageCorners.at(0).x  ,xMax = imageCorners.at(0).x; 
            int yMin = imageCorners.at(0).y, yMax =imageCorners.at(0).y;
        for (int i  = (imageCorners.size()-1) ; i>0;i--){
                if(xMin > imageCorners.at(i-1).x)
                        xMin = imageCorners.at(i-1).x;
                if(xMax < imageCorners.at(i-1).x)
                    xMax = imageCorners.at(i-1).x;
                if(yMin > imageCorners.at(i-1).y)
                    yMin = imageCorners.at(i-1).y;
                if(yMax < imageCorners.at(i-1).y)
                    yMax = imageCorners.at(i-1).y;
            } 
        cv::Rect  myroi(xMin-5,yMin-5,(xMax-xMin)+5,(yMax-yMin)+5);
        if ( myroi.area() > 0){
            cv::imshow("ROI",(src)(myroi));  
        result = (src)(myroi);
        not_a_rect_shape.clear();
        not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[0]);
        not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[board.height-1]);
        not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[board.area()-board.height-1]);
        not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[board.area()-1]);
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> approx;
        cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(not_a_rect_shape),approx,cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(not_a_rect_shape),true)*0.02,true);
        if (approx.size()!=4){
            std::cout << " Not quadrilateral!"<<std::endl;

            not_a_rect_shape.clear();
            approx.clear();

            not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[0]);
            not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[board.width-1]);
            not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[board.area()-board.width-1]);
            not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[board.area()-1]);
            cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(not_a_rect_shape),approx,cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(not_a_rect_shape),true)*0.02,true); 
        }

        // center 
        cv::Point2f center(0,0);
        for (int i = 0 ; i <not_a_rect_shape.size(); i++)
                center+= not_a_rect_shape[i];
            center *=( 1./not_a_rect_shape.size()); // the center position 

            top.clear();
            bot.clear();
        // ordering  the  4 points 
        for (int i = 0; i < not_a_rect_shape.size(); i++){
            if (not_a_rect_shape[i].y < center.y)
                top.push_back(not_a_rect_shape[i]);
            else
                 bot.push_back(not_a_rect_shape[i]);
            }
        std::cout << center << std::endl;
        if(top.size()== 2 && bot.size()==2){ 
            cv::Point2f tl = top[0].x > top[1].x ? top[1] : top[0];
            cv::Point2f tr = top[0].x > top[1].x ? top[0] : top[1];
            cv::Point2f bl = bot[0].x > bot[1].x ? bot[1] : bot[0];
            cv::Point2f br = bot[0].x > bot[1].x ? bot[0] : bot[1];
            not_a_rect_shape.clear();
            not_a_rect_shape.push_back(tl);
            not_a_rect_shape.push_back(tr);
            not_a_rect_shape.push_back(br);
            not_a_rect_shape.push_back(bl);

            // Define the destination image
            quad = cv::Mat::zeros(300, 220, CV_8UC3);
            //quad = cv::Mat::zeros(result.rows,result.cols,CV_8UC3);
        // Corners of the destination image
            std::vector<cv::Point2f> quad_pts;
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, 0));
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, quad.rows));
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, quad.rows));
            transformationMatrix= cv::getPerspectiveTransform(not_a_rect_shape, quad_pts);
            cv::warpPerspective(src, quad, transformationMatrix, quad.size()/*perspectiveSize*/,1);
            cv::imshow("quadrilateral", quad);
            cv::imwrite("result.jpg",result);
            cv::imwrite("quadrilateral.jpg",quad);

        }

        }
        }
        cv::imshow("src",src); 
        key = cv::waitKey(10);
    }
```

This an example of a ROI that get :

[image: quadrilateral]

And this is how it look like after changing the perspective :

[image: result]

And let's say  this is what  I expect (this size doesn't matter):

[image: expected]

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the next code snippet for such problems:

```
...
// Create a column vector with the coordinates of each point (on the field plane)
cv::Mat xField;
xField.create(4, 1, CV_32FC2);
xField.at<Point2f>(0) = ( Pts[0] );
xField.at<Point2f>(1) = ( Pts[1] );
xField.at<Point2f>(2) = ( Pts[2] );
xField.at<Point2f>(3) = ( Pts[3] );

// same thing for xImage but with the pixel coordinates instead of the field coordinates, same order as in xField
cv::Mat xImage;
xImage.create(4, 1, CV_32FC2);
xImage.at<Point2f>(0) = ( cv::Point2f(0, 0) );
xImage.at<Point2f>(1) = ( cv::Point2f(400, 0) );
xImage.at<Point2f>(2) = ( cv::Point2f(400, 600) );
xImage.at<Point2f>(3) = ( cv::Point2f(0, 600) );

// Compute the homography matrix
cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(xField,xImage );
xField.release();
xImage.release();

Mat warped;
warpPerspective(frame,warped,H,Size(400,600));
H.release();
...
```

this code will get image from polygon xField and put it to xImage (here it is rectangle 0,0,400,600).

You mistake here:
change this

```
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(tl);
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(tr);
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(br);
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(bl);
```

to this

```
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[0]);
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[board.area()-board.width]);
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[board.area()-1]);
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(imageCorners[board.width-1]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm doing all most the same, the way you're using findHomography make it doing the same thing as getPerspektiveTransform ! and using the  Mat instead of vector of Point doesn't change anythings here !

Comment: I have edited my answer, you have set points coods not correct.

Comment: it works, but I don't understand why I should do it like this???  I'll accept your answer but please I need a little bit explication

Comment: This works because such way you'll get corners of rotated board.When you finding min/max along x and y axis you mix all x and y's of corner points. Try draw it on paper.