# Perspective transform given point (x,y) in quadrilateral plane to Rectangle plane's point (x', y')?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, perspective

I am trying **to transform quadrilateral to rectangular plane** And **need to extract coordinate of 1 specific point (in quadrilateral plane), to that in respect to rectangular plane**..

I'm using EmguCV for image processing purpose in my .NET project

What I've tried is:

1) Calculate Homography matrix between quadrilateral and rectangular plane (specifying points in clockwise order from left top corner for both planes)

2) Multiply above Homography matrix by 3 x 1 matrix [x,y,1] to get final coordinates.

However, the resultant coordinate (x', y') does not seem in concordance with given point (x,y).

[image]

Comment: Did you dehomogenize the coordinates? After multiplication you have (x',y',z') but you need (x',y',1) so calculate p' = (x'/z', y'/z'). If you did that and still got wrong results, try drawing the whole rectangle and show the results please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181012/changing-the-perspective-using-opencv

Comment: @Micka, Thanks a ton !! That "Dehomogenization" was way to go.. It solved my problem. It's strange how I forget basic thing required. i.e. p' = (x'/z', y'/z') Thanks again!

Comment: if you like you can post an answer yourself (maybe code) and accept it to help others who have the same problem (and see this question to be answered).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka) suggested, after having resultant matrix (3x1), all that is needed to solve this problem was this: **p' = (x'/z', y'/z')**

**Steps as below:**

1. Calculate Homography matrix between quadrilateral and rectangular plane
2. Multiply this homography mat. with candidate point [x,y,1]T and get [x',y',z']T
3. Now, Dehomogenize above [x',y',z']T   i.e. **[(x'/z'), (y'/z'), 1]T**

   thus, the required final coordinate of rectangular plane.